# Input Field On Top Of Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mobile

I've looked around for an answer, but couldn't find anything after a while. I'm running jQuery mobile and have a list view with a bunch of li's that I want to be both links and input fields. But when I click to input in the text field, it automatically presses the button as well.

Basically what I'm trying to do is have an input form that a user can modify, and then have them click anywhere outside of the form to submit the changes.

Is there anyway to get around this?

```
echo "<li data-icon='false'>![enter image description here][1]
    <a href='javascript: updateName()'> Name of Conversation: 
        <form name='name' action='update.php' method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='" . $this->conversation->get_name() . "'/>
        </form>
    </a>
</li>";
```

And if anyone is wondering what updateName() does:

```
function updateName(){
    document.name.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've wrapped the `input` in an `<a>` tag. When you click the `<input>`, the click event bubbles up to the `<a>` and triggered `updateName`

You can bind a handler for the click event of input and call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling to parent `<a>`, as follows:

```
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('click',function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
function updateName(){
 document.name.submit();
}
```

Comment: I got that part, is there anyway to circumvent that without losing the look?

Comment: Hmm. For some reason that isn't working for me. I'm including the script before all of the list logic, but it still isn't stopping it from following the link. Basically what I'm trying to do is have an input form that a user can modify, and then have them click anywhere outside of the form to submit the changes. Is this at all feasible? Any suggestions?

Comment: "I'm including the script before all of the list logic" you have to add the script at the very bottom of `<body>`, or in `window.onload` event, otherwise the script while executed before the elements are created and hence nothing will work...

Answer (score 0):

You should just attach a listener to the `blur` event of your field, which will trigger when you field loses focus. Just check that you user put something into the field before doing anything, otherwise any click or tab at the wrong moment would become quickly unnerving.

For the link that surround it, I can't understand why you're doing something like that. If you really need a link, put it alongside your field but not around.